# keep array in Vector/ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, vector

Do I keep many arrays in a vector?
I want like this...
[{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}]

I am trying in this way and get error.

```
          Vector< int[]> v=new Vector();
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                int a[]=new int[3];
                for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                    a[j]=ob.nextInt();
                }
                v.add(a);
            }
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                System.out.println(v.get(i));
            }
```

I know this way

```
         Vector< Vector<Integer>> v=new Vector();
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            Vector< Integer> v1=new Vector();
                for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                    v1.add(ob.nextInt());
                }
                v.add(v1);
            }
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                System.out.println(v.get(i));
            }
```

But I want to keep those element (in a vector) using array .Can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use NOT primitive type with

```
Vector<Integer[]> v = new Vector();
```

But, what's the problem? Where is the error?

```
 Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\s");
 int n = 2;
 Vector<int[]> v = new Vector();
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     int[] a = new int[3];
     for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
         a[j] = ob.nextInt();
     }
     v.add(a);
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v.get(i))); //change output
 }
```

**Input**: 1 2 3 4 5 6

**Output**:
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]

Answer (score 1):

If you really want use `Vector`, you can try something like this (I assume, your `ob` is `Random` object):

```java
Random ob = new Random();
final int n = 3;

Vector<int[]> v = new Vector<>();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int[] a = new int[n];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        a[j] = ob.nextInt();
    }
    v.add(a);
}

for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) { //changed
    for (int j = 0; j < v.get(i).length; j++) {
        System.out.println(v.get(i)[j]);
    }
}
```

you were probably surprised by the display of `int []` on your console. In my case:

```
[I@7229724f
[I@4c873330
[I@119d7047
```

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array).

But I recommend **change `Vector` to `List`** (you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-and-stack-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated) for more details).